# Looking for a regex to parse a string of malformed HTML

Tags: python, parsing

I am looking for a regex pattern that will help me get from this messy HTML that is parsed with wrong tags:

```html
<dt>Released
<dd>2019-02-13 <dt>First review
<dd>2019-02-13
<dt>Age
<dd>
914 days (2.5 years)
</dd></dt></dd></dt></dd></dt>
```

To this:

```
2019-02-13
2019-02-13
914 days (2.5 years)
```

Now it seems that the easiest way to approach this is to convert the original class to string and use regex to extract the correct values. I wonder what regex should I use.

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use an HTML parser:

```py
>>> html = '''<dt>Released
... <dd>2019-02-13 <dt>First review
... <dd>2019-02-13
... <dt>Age
... <dd>
... 914 days (2.5 years)
... </dd></dt></dd></dt></dd></dt>'''
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> [x.text for x in BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml").find_all("dd")]
['2019-02-13 ', '2019-02-13\n', '\n914 days (2.5 years)\n']
```

(use `x.text.strip()` if you don't want whitespace)

If it's not clear what's going on here, the HTML parser (lxml) actually *fixes the HTML for you* (amazing!!):

```py
>>> BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
<html><body><dt>Released
</dt><dd>2019-02-13 </dd><dt>First review
</dt><dd>2019-02-13
</dd><dt>Age
</dt><dd>
914 days (2.5 years)
</dd></body></html>
```

Not the case with the builtin html.parser:

```py
>>> BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
<dt>Released
<dd>2019-02-13 <dt>First review
<dd>2019-02-13
<dt>Age
<dd>
914 days (2.5 years)
</dd></dt></dd></dt></dd></dt>
>>> [x.text.strip() for x in BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find_all("dd")]
['2019-02-13 First review\n2019-02-13\nAge\n\n914 days (2.5 years)', '2019-02-13
\nAge\n\n914 days (2.5 years)', '914 days (2.5 years)']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\D*(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\D*(\d* days \(.*\))
```

This may help you. It captures the:

- `$1` and `$2`: The First and second dates with the `dddd-dd-dd` (d for digit) format.
- `$3`: The string with `anynumber days (anything in the parentheses)` format.

You can check it with [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) website:
[image: regex in action from regex101 website]